# PLOT TWIST: How to combine multiple XML files AND output multiple nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt

Having searched here and on dozens of other pages for solutions to similar problems, I thought this would be easy. However, I can't get this to work.

I have a large set of XML files that all use the same structure. Certain branches can repeat. To combine them into one document, I created a stylesheet that uses the document function. In addition, I use for-each to output the nodes in each instance of msItem.

However, the output defective. Instead of giving the value of each node together with the values of the corresponding nodes, I get the values of all the nodes. For every msItem I get the exact same garbled lines.

Who can help?

Ms_01.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI version="5.0" xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<msDesc>
    <msIdentifier>
        <idno type="shelfmark">Ms. 01</idno>
    </msIdentifier>
    <msContents>
        <msItem>
            <locus from="1r" to="15v">1r-15v</locus>
            <author>
                <persName xml:lang="en">Aristotle</persName>
                <persName xml:lang="gr">…</persName>
            </author>
            <title xml:lang="en">On the sould</title>
            <title xml:lang="he">…</title>
        </msItem>
        <msItem>
            <locus from="16r" to="25v">16r-25v</locus>
            <author>
                <persName xml:lang="en">Aristotle</persName>
                <persName xml:lang="gr">…</persName>
            </author>
            <title xml:lang="en">On Generation and Corruption</title>
            <title xml:lang="he">…</title>
        </msItem>
        <msItem>
            <locus from="26r" to="35v">26r-35v</locus>
            <author>
                <persName xml:lang="en">Aristotle</persName>
                <persName xml:lang="gr">…</persName>
            </author>
            <title xml:lang="en">Physics</title>
            <title xml:lang="he">…</title>
        </msItem>
    </msContents>
</msDesc>
</TEI>
```

Ms_02.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI version="5.0" xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<msDesc>
    <msIdentifier>
        <idno type="shelfmark">Ms. 02</idno>
    </msIdentifier>
    <msContents>
        <msItem>
            <locus from="1r" to="15v">1r-15v</locus>
            <author>
                <persName xml:lang="en">Plato</persName>
                <persName xml:lang="gr">…</persName>
            </author>
            <title xml:lang="en">Ion</title>
            <title xml:lang="he">…</title>
        </msItem>
        <msItem>
            <locus from="16r" to="25v">16r-25v</locus>
            <author>
                <persName xml:lang="en">Plato</persName>
                <persName xml:lang="gr">…</persName>
            </author>
            <title xml:lang="en">Republic</title>
            <title xml:lang="he">…</title>
        </msItem>
    </msContents>
</msDesc>
</TEI>
```

booklist_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<library>
    <title>Selected Manuscripts</title>
    <book filename="Ms_01.xml"/>
    <book filename="Ms_02.xml"/>
</library>
```

The XSLT-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
  <!--<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>-->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="document(/library/book/@filename)//tei:msItem">
      <xsl:sort select="//tei:persName[@xml:lang='en']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:persName[@xml:lang='en']"/>
      <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:title[@xml:lang='en']"/>
      <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:idno[@type='shelfmark']"/>
      <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:locus"/>
      <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The desired output:

```
Aristotle; On the soul; Ms. 01; 1r-15v
Aristotle; On Generation and Corruption; Ms. 01; 16r-25v
Aristotle; Physics; Ms. 01; 26r-35v
Plato; Ion; Ms. 02; 1r-15v
Plato; Republic; Ms. 02; 16r-25v
```

The output I get:

```
AristotleAristotleAristotle; On the souldOn Generation and CorruptionPhysics; Ms. 01; 1r-15v16r-25v26r-35v
AristotleAristotleAristotle; On the souldOn Generation and CorruptionPhysics; Ms. 01; 1r-15v16r-25v26r-35v
AristotleAristotleAristotle; On the souldOn Generation and CorruptionPhysics; Ms. 01; 1r-15v16r-25v26r-35v
PlatoPlato; IonRepublic; Ms. 02; 1r-15v16r-25v
PlatoPlato; IonRepublic; Ms. 02; 1r-15v16r-25v
```

Comment: "Having searched here and on dozens of other pages for solutions to similar problems". You know, that's not actually a good strategy for tackling a new problem. Sure, read lots of examples while you are learning a language, but once you're doing real programming, rely on your knowledge of the building blocks of the language, not on finding someone who has already written the same program.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was simply that you used *global* paths like `//...` instead of specific paths like the ones below. By using a global XPath expression like `"//tei:persName[@xml:lang='en']"` you did refer to all `tei:persName` in each iteration. But by using a specific path like I did below (`"tei:author/tei:persName[@xml:lang='en']"`), you only match this path once relative to the `current()` node.

Hence the whole template is/should be full of *specific* XPath expressions giving you the desired output:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="document(/library/book/@filename)/tei:TEI/tei:msDesc/tei:msContents/tei:msItem">
      <xsl:sort select="tei:author/tei:persName[@xml:lang='en']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:author/tei:persName[@xml:lang='en']"/>
      <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:title[@xml:lang='en']"/>
      <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../../tei:msIdentifier/tei:idno[@type='shelfmark']"/>
      <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:locus"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
Aristotle; On the sould; Ms. 01; 1r-15v
Aristotle; On Generation and Corruption; Ms. 01; 16r-25v
Aristotle; Physics; Ms. 01; 26r-35v
Plato; Ion; Ms. 02; 1r-15v
Plato; Republic; Ms. 02; 16r-25v
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Very much obliged!

How would I merge each instance of the persName to achieve an output like this?

    Aristotle; Ms. 01
    Plato; Ms. 02

Comment: That's a whole different question, a grouping question. If you're stuck with XSLT-1.0, look for [Muenchian Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Muenchian+GRouping) on StackOverflow. If you can use XSLT-2.0 or above, look for `xsl:for-each-group`.